# Visualizing json data as table in POSTMAN

Tags: html, json, postman

I want to visualize json response in postman as a table.

I've put something like this into the "test" tab in postman

```
let gitdata = pm.response.json();
let template = 
`
 <table bgcolor="#FFFFGF">
        <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>id</th>    {{company}}        
        </tr>

        {{#each gitdata }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{login}}</td>
                <td>{{ID}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`
//console.log(gitdata);//

pm.visualizer.set(template, gitdata)
```

I don't get it how the "{{#each" part of the code works. Sending requests shows empty table in "visualize" tab although "pretty" tab shows results like this:

```
{
    "login": "string",
    "id": int,
    "node_id": "string",
    "avatar_url": "url",
    "gravatar_id": "",
and so on...
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Your response does not have an array so you wouldn't need to use that handlebars block to access the data. https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### #Each

now about #each , is an iterator . It allows you to loop through all the elements in the value object of value object is an array.

if value is an object it gives you the value of the object and it can be accessed as {{this}}

First thing, You have to expose the data as an object in the visualizer,

```
pm.visualiser.set(template, {"somekey":"value"})
```

now access the value inside the template as {{somekey}}

**Example 1: Array**

```
let gitdata = [{ "login": "Login1", "ID": "id1" }, { "login": "Login2", "ID": "id2" }, { "login": "Login3", "ID": "id3" }];
let template =
    `
 <table bgcolor="#FFFFGF">
        <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>id</th>    {{company}}        
        </tr>

        {{#each data }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{login}}</td>
                <td>{{ID}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`
//console.log(gitdata);//

pm.visualizer.set(template, { "data": gitdata })
```

**Example 2: Object**

```
let gitdata = { "login": "Login1", "ID": "id1" };
let template =
    `
 <table bgcolor="#FFFFGF">
        <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>id</th>    {{company}}        
        </tr>

        {{#each data }}
            
         
                <td>{{this}}</td>
               
            
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`
//console.log(gitdata);//

pm.visualizer.set(template, { "data": gitdata })
```

**Now in your case you just want to access specific fields so you don,t have to use each , instead just call the field explicitly like @Danny mentioned:**

```
let gitdata = { "login": "Login1", "ID": "id1" };
let template =
    `
 <table bgcolor="#FFFFGF">
        <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>id</th>    {{company}}        
        </tr>

        
            <tr>
         
                <td>{{login}}</td>
                 <td>{{ID}}</td>
               
            </tr>
        
    </table>
`
//console.log(gitdata);//

pm.visualizer.set(template, gitdata )
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. I've modified test for another endpoint I'm using and it works :) each reply is shown in separate row in the table which is what I wanted.